# select2 - tagging of terms without restrictions

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I use select2 widely and data is pulled via ajax in all cases. But for one field, I need to let users type terms of their choice and I should covert those to tags. 
How can i let select2 do tagging not bound to pre-defined values (like ajax). Just free text as user decides? 
I use Select2 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it... Looks like the below construct allows free tagging...

```
$("#inp_select2_b").select2(
    {
        placeholder: "Add your tags here",
        maximumSelectionLength: 5,
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true
    }
);
```